# How to support HTML5 audio tag in older versions of Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio

I am trying to play a simple audio file using `audio` tag with `autoplay` set to `true`. It works fine in chrome,firefox but having no luck in Internet Explorer older versions. How to fix this ?

**Code I am trying:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sound_notification"></div>
<button id="playButton" onclick="messageNotification()">Play</button>
<script>
//TODO sound notification for incoming message

function messageNotification()
{
    console.log("inside notification handler");
    var filename="sound/notify";
    document.getElementById("sound_notification").innerHTML='<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="' + filename + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="' + filename + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" src="' + filename +'.mp3" /></audio>';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know HTML5 audio is not supported below IE9. I don't want the flash fall back as the user might not have flash player installed. What approach would you follow in this scenerio ?

Comment: Because `HTML5` wont supports in Internet explorer 9 or below

Comment: @ubercooluk I thought that initially too, but the OP has a fallback in there using the `<embed>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the `<bgsound>` tag which is only supported by IE. It served my purpose.

**For supporting IE:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- this tag is only supported by IE -->
<bgsound id="notification">
<button id="playButton" onclick="messageNotification()">Play</button>
<script>
//TODO sound notification for incoming message

function messageNotification()
{
    document.getElementById("notification").src="sound/notify.mp3";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```